# Solve for $c$ in an equation involving modulo operation (remainder after division)

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have reduced a part of a programming task to this equation:

$(c*a+1)\%b=1$ where $c\geq 1,0\leq a<b$

For a given $a$ and $b$ I want to find the smallest value of $c$ such that the equation is satisfied.

Right now what I have implemented is:

```
c=1  
i=a+1;
while(i!=1)
{
   i+=a;
   if(i>b)i-=b;
   ++c;
}
```

This is an O(n) implementation and is not very efficient. I was looking for a O(1) implementation i.e. if there is any way we can directly find such $c$ without a loop?

Comment: Well first of all, know that modulos can be distributed on sum and multiplication.

Comment: Okay so $(c*a+1)\%b=1$ can be written as $(c*a+1)-b*((c*a+1)/b)=1$. Right? Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your programming equation $(c*a+1)\%b=1$ would normally be written by mathematicians like

$$ca+1 \equiv 1 \pmod b$$

That simplifies to

$$ca \equiv 0 \pmod b$$

which we can easily prove:

$ca+1 \equiv 1 \pmod b \implies ca+1 = kb + 1$ for some integer $k$.
So $ca = kb$

To find $c$, let $a=gA, b=gB$, where $g$ is the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $a$ & $b$, $g = \gcd(a, b)$.

Then $cgA = kgB \implies cA = kB$.

Now $B$ doesn't divide $A$ so it must divide $c$, so the smallest (positive) value for $c$ is $B$ (and hence $k = A$). The proof of that is known as [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

In other words $c = b / \gcd(a, b)$

Note that $ac = AgB = A(gB) = Ab$, so it's a multiple of both $a$ and $b$.

So how do we find $\gcd(a, b)$?

The usual method is to use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) which utilizes the fact that for $a < b$,

$$\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b\mod a, a)$$

Here's an implementation in Python.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
```

That function assumes that $a >=b$; it still works if $a<b$, but it takes one extra loop, or you can do a compare and swap before the loop, if you like.